# Scrapy can't find spider

Tags: python, shell, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm inching my way through this ([1](http://www.hackhowtofaq.com/blog/web-scraping-with-scrapy/)) tutorial.

I'm working in a folder I created as a scrapy project from the command line:

> Users/myname/Desktop/MyProject/MyProject/Spider/MyProject_spider.py

My code is

```
import [everything necessary]

class myProjectSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'myProject'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/listentothis']
    start_urls = ['http://www.reddit.com/r/listentothis']
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('http://www.reddit.com/r/listentothis/.+'), deny_domains=('www.youtube.com', 'www.soundcloud.com', 'www.reddit.com/user/.+')),'parse_start_url',follow=False),)

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        title1 = hxs.select('class="Title"').extract(text)
        yield request
```

In the command line, I navigate to Desktop>MyProject and enter

```
scrapy crawl myProject
```

The error I always get is

> "Spider not found: myProject."

I've tried using different names (making the spider name match the class name, making the class lame match the file name, making the file name match the project name, and every combination of the above), and I tried calling the command from different files in the project.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, that dot is just a typo. Don't know how that got in there.

Answer (score 0):

From the current folder you need to run `scrapy runspider MyProject_spider`
and if you want to crawl you need to create a project,place MyProject_Spider.py in the spider directory and then go to the top level directory and run `scrapy crawl myProject`.

Answer (score 0):

try going into your folders and inside the spider folder copy the path, and paste it into your terminal  "cd C:\Users\PC\Desktop...........\bookscraper\bookscraper\spiders"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTjSQ.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).